# My wife has an interview for a job in Australia (we are based in London). What can I do in terms of a visa if she is offered / takes the job?

Tags: australia

My wife and I are based in London.

She has an interview (being held in London) for a teaching job in Australia (Ballarat, specifically), starting in January 2018.

I work as a Data Scientist and I understand that my profession is listed on the Skilled Occupations List, too.

Assuming she gets the job, what options are there for me in terms of a visa?

Also, assuming that I can go over with her and that everything is taken care of in terms of a visa, do we have to live in Ballarat or can we live anywhere ("where" we live isn't relevant in the context of this question)?

I have read multiple texts stating that we will be limited to living only in the area where she acquires work for at least 2 years; is there a visa that we can apply for which will allow us to live anywhere, regardless of the job location?

Comment: Good question, can you edit the title to match the body of the question more accurately?  Title is very broad, body of question is much better focussed!

Comment: Title has been updated.

Comment: Australia is a huge country, travel times between cities can be very long. How far from Ballarat would you be planning to live? Would you be commuting?

Comment: We were thinking of Melbourne, which is around 90 minutes away; however, the "where" we live isn't necessarily the problem here - I suppose we should think of the "where" as anywhere that is within reasonable committung distance from Ballarat, say  between one and two hours.

Comment: If she gets a geographically restricted visa, she must abide by the restriction. I saw an article recently where a couple were being deported because they were one neighborhood away from their visa-restricted allowed area. I think they were self-employed though so maybe working in the area would be enough.

Comment: If she gets a 190 visa, she can live in Melbourne. If it's a 489 (skilled regional), she is not allowed to live nor work in Melbourne for either 2 or 3 years.

Answer (score 2):

**It's going to depend on the visa she gets.**  If she gets the [Temporary Work (Skilled) visa (subclass 457)](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/457-), which is the most likely option, as her partner you will have unrestricted work rights.  However, if she gets the [Skilled Regional (Provisional) visa (subclass 489)](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/489-), your work and residency rights will also be restricted to the region; this means your employer has to be within the region as well.  The specific areas where you can live on a regional visa are [defined by postcode here](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Work/Work/Allocation-dates-for-General-Skilled-Migration-applications/regional-growth).

Note that Ballarat is a small country town without much demand for data scientists.  However, it's (barely) within commuting distance from Melbourne (115 km by car, 1:40 by train), where you should be able to find a job fairly easily if your visa permits, and you could split the difference by living around the halfway mark at a place like [Bacchus Marsh](https://goo.gl/maps/K43f1Zjeb2u).

The final option would be for you to apply independently, either for your own 457 visa (fast, but requires a sponsoring employer) or a skilled migration visa (no sponsor needed, but very slow).